# Find out the number of rows/columns changed - SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, catalog-views

I found `row/colmodctr` options in `sys.sysindexes` but this has no equivalent in `sys.indexes`. Because `sys.indexes` is the recommended catalog view how can I find row and column change number without using `sys.sysindexes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because sys.indexes is the recommended catalog view...

The reason behind non-using of `row/colmodctr` is another one (you can find it in [sys.sysindexes (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-compatibility-views/sys-sysindexes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) article:

> In SQL Server 2000 and earlier, the Database Engine maintained
>   **row-level** modification counters. Such counters **are now maintained at
>   the column level**. Therefore, the rowmodctr column is calculated and
>   produces results that are similar to the results in earlier versions,
>   but are not exact.
>
> If you use the value in rowmodctr to determine when to update
>   statistics, consider the following solutions:
>
> Do nothing. The new rowmodctr value will frequently help you determine
>   when to update statistics because the behavior is reasonably close to
>   the results of earlier versions.
>
> Use AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS. For more information see, Statistics.
>
> Use a time limit to determine when to update statistics. For example,
>   every hour, every day, or every week.
>
> Use application-level information to determine when to update
>   statistics. For example, every time the maximum value of an identity
>   column changes by more than 10,000, or every time a bulk insert
>   operation is performed.

So now you can use `modification_counter` column of [sys.dm_db_stats_properties (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-stats-properties-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the statistics of interest:

> modification_counter
>
> Total number of modifications for the leading
>   statistics column (the column on which the histogram is built) since
>   the last time statistics were updated.